# Certain files crash when opened in Blender

Tags: system

A few Blender files I have crash immediately upon being opened. I am using Blender V.3.6.5 on a Mac with OSV10.15.7 (Catalina).

All the files that crash were originally made in Blender V2.79 according to my text editor app. What could be causing the crashes?

Comment: Incompatibility. Maybe you should try to make a new scene and append content from the old file into the new file. Hard to say without knowing the files what exactly makes them crash - and therefore it's also hard to tell which parts you can append in a new file and which not.

Comment: Do 2.79 files not work in 3.6? I thought there was backwards compatibility.

Comment: Blender strives to have backward and forward compatibility, but there are exceptions. Usually on main versions e.g. going from 2.x to 3.x and 4.x there are breakages of this rule. In general, LTS versions of a previous version should be able to work as a converter between the old and new main versions. Crashes could be considered as bugs in these. But as I said: without (maybe even with) knowing your files we cannot determine if there are critical parts which could cause crashes or if there is a bug, since we are no Blender developers here and only answer questions on working with Blender.

Comment: So what you might want to try is downloading 2.83 LTS, try to open the files with this version and save them again with the LTS version. Then either try to open those with 3.6.5 or get Blender 3.3 LTS and try it with this version.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, I think this could have been posted as an answer instead of comments. I think this is the answer.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys But it could still be a bug and I never tried this if it works. This is what the Blender developer page says about backward and forward compatibility. I never tried opening such old files with such a big gap between versions. So I'm not going to post an answer which I do not have the slightest idea if it really works and then get a lot of downvotes because it does not ;) I just wanted to make some suggestions from what I read on those developer pages.

Comment: [This one](https://developer.blender.org/docs/handbook/guidelines/compatibility_handling_for_blend_files/), right? I don't know... looks like quite an official source, to me at least. But it does say "Any crash or file corruption caused by loading a file saved with an older version of Blender is considered as a severe or critical bug." Hm. interesting. Maybe reporting a bug could be a good idea then.